# Winsock client socket - Blocking dynamic ports in the firewall

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock, windows-firewall

- Consider a server socket and a client socket.
- The server socket endpoint is identified by the pair (IP/ `Ws.Xs.Ys.Zs`, TCP port/ `Ps`).
- When the client socket initiates a connection with the server socket, the client endpoint gets associated with the pair (IP/ `Wc.Xc.Yc.Zc`, TCP Port/ `Pc`).
- The client socket is a "Winsock".
- On the client machine, outbound traffic for port `Ps` is NOT blocked.
- At connection time, `Pc` is automatically chosen in the pool of ephemeral/dynamic ports of the client machine.
- The client socket sends a message `Mc` to the server socket.
- The server socket responds and sends a message `Ms` back to the client socket.
- This message will be addressed to the endpoint identified by (IP/ `Wc.Xc.Yc.Zc`, TCP Port/ `Pc`).

Is there a way I can block this message `Ms` by setting up a firewall rule in the "Inbound" section of the firewall on the client machine?

I have tried to set up such a rule but it seems not to block anything:

```
In the Windows firewall, in the "Inbound" rules section:
- "New Rule..." -> "Port"
- TCP
- Specific local ports: 49152-65535
  (This is the dynamic ports range on the client machine (given by the command "netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp")).
- Block the connection
- When does this rule apply? I checked: "Domain", "Private" and "Public".
```

Why is it not working? Why is `Ms` not rejected by the firewall?
Is it because of the socket implementation? Something like: if the client socket could actually send its message to the server socket then the response from the server has to be accepted on (IP/ `Wc.Xc.Yc.Zc`, TCP Port/ `Pc`) even if there is a blocking rule in the firewall?
Or maybe, the rule I'm setting above is not actually blocking what I think it is blocking...

Thank you for helping.
Best regards.

Comment: Why? If you want to block the connection, block the connection. Allowing the connect and then trying to block messages via that connection doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

A firewall blocks connection attempts, not individual packets.  An outbound filter prevents an outbound connection to a remote server, an inbound filter prevents an inbound connection to a local server.

Besides that, a "message" may require more than one packet be transmitted, or may be grouped with other "messages" in a single packet.

So no, once a connection has been successfully established, a firewall cannot block specific "messages" being transmitted over that connection.  The connection has already been trusted, the firewall does not analyze and filter the connection's content.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for these explanations.